# Youtube api oAuth 400 origin mismatch

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-javascript-api

I use JS youtube api and try upload video at
http://newauto46.ru/youtube/upload_video.html
Then a had configured origin url at developers console.
Now I have 400 origin mismatch error 
Request Details

```
=
proxy=oauth2relay538900249
scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube
origin=http://newauto46.ru
response_type=code token id_token gsession
redirect_uri=postmessage
state=678581604|0.3528401798
pageId=106287838926302036687
client_id=1034451067661-h7v9fipq91k83log7c47f49l1o257rl4.apps.googleusercontent.com
cookie_policy=single_host_origin
include_granted_scopes=true
```

What can I do with it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I forgot that you need to paste client_id into auth.js AND upload_video.html